# Using DLImageLoader-iOS

Tags: image

Is there anyone that can help me combine this

https://github.com/AndreyLunevich/DLImageLoader-iOS

With my code below... I am not understanding as my images are loaded from an NSString in core data and not a URL (maybe I cannot use this helper file)

My code is:

```
SCTableViewSection *Section3 = [self.tableViewModel sectionAtIndex:0];
    Section3.cellActions.lazyLoad = ^(SCTableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath)

    {

        DLImageView *imageView = (DLImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        NSString *imageString = (NSString *)[cell.boundObject valueForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@", imageString];
        NSString *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fullName];
        UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        NSLog(@"added image from lazyload");

        // size of actual thumbnail to display in cell
        CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(154,95); // size of actual thumbnail
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
        [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
        UIImage *thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [UIView transitionWithView:imageView
                          duration:2.25f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^{
                            imageView.image = thumbnail;
                        } completion:nil];

    };
```

Comment: Do you have an image in this line -> UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]; ?

Comment: and try ti use [imageView setNeedsDisplay]; after imageView.image = thumbnail.